# Parsing command output in .NET

Tags: .net, parsing, string, unidata

I want to connect up to a database server in my .NET app and execute a database command that produces a series of database statistics.  The problem is that it doesn't return the stats in a structured format, it returns it in plain text (like a `df -k` command in UNIX)  I can capture the output and parse it, but I was wondering if there's a better approach to something like this.

I certainly can't think of an alternative, but I wanted to ask around. It seems a little fragile to be parsing the command results because if the database author ever changes the format, I break.

**Edit:** The database is an IBM UniData database.  The command is "file.stat" and it returns the average record size, max record size, etc.

Comment: Is there any other way to connect to that base?

Comment: What's the command? Perhaps someone here knows another way of returning the same data in a more structured format.

Comment: Maybe the results of that database command are also stored in the database itself, in some kind of table/view? If that is the case you can query those tables/view.

Comment: I can't edit your question, but you might want to add the tag unidata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, parse for the description.  However, you should check the database version first.

```
:version
Module Name         Version   Licensed
UniData RDBMS............ 7.1     Yes
```

That way if the file.stat data changes, you could call alternate routines.
**Note:** The file.stat output data has been static for sometime and is unlikely to change.

```
:file.stat TEST

File name                             = TEST
Number of groups in file (modulo)     = 3
Static hashing, hash type             = 0
Block size                            = 2048
Number of records                     = 12
Total number of bytes                 = 2335

Average number of records per group   = 4.0
Standard deviation from average       = 1.0
Average number of bytes per group     = 778.3
Standard deviation from average       = 286.2

Average number of bytes in a record   = 194.6
Average number of bytes in record ID  = 4.3
Standard deviation from average       = 42.3
Minimum number of bytes in a record   = 113
Maximum number of bytes in a record   = 270

Minimum number of fields in a record  = 66
Maximum number of fields in a record  = 80
Average number of fields per record   = 72.7
Standard deviation from average       = 6.5
The actual file size in bytes         = 8192.
```